# Android where file is saved FileOutputStream

Tags: android, file, save

Here how I write bytes to a file. I'm using `FileOutputStream`

```
    private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
                        byte[] readBuffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                        FileOutputStream out = null;
                        try {
                            out = new FileOutputStream("myFile.xml");
                            out.write(readBuffer);
                            out.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
           }
}
```

and now I want to open that file, so I need to have path of that file. So how I need to open that file?

EDIT:

Here how I read from file, but I can't see anything...

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
                    FileInputStream s = null;
                    try {
                        s = new FileInputStream("mano.xml");
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));

                        String line = reader.readLine();
                        Log.d(getTag(), line);
                        while (line != null) {
                            Log.d(getTag(), line);
                            line = reader.readLine();
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: You probably are crashing, as `new FileOutputStream("myFile.xml")` has no meaning on Android. If you wish to store `myFile.xml` in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), use something like: `new FileOutputStream(new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "myFile.xml"))`. If you wish to store `myFile.xml` in [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), use something like: `new FileOutputStream(new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "myFile.xml"))`.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use this for writting:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/yourfilename");
```

So to read the location:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+transaction.getUniqueId()+".pdf");
```

To read the path:

```
file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

How it is reported inside the developers guide you have to specify where you want to save your file. You can choose between:

1. Saving the file in the internal storage:

   ```
   String filename = "myfile";
   String string = "Hello world!";
   FileOutputStream outputStream;

   try {
     outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
     outputStream.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. Or on second instance you could save your file in external storage:

   ```
   // Checks if external storage is available to at least read
   public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
     String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
     if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
       return true;
     }
     return false;
   }
   ```

Just remember to set permissions!!!!

Here there is the entire documentation: [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your file is save in path `/Data/Data/Your package Name/files/myFile.xml`
you can use `this.getFileDir()` method to get the path of the files folder on the Application.

So use `this.getFileDir() +  "myFile.xml"` to read the file.